# CASE statement in MYSQL trigger

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Most of the info about this topic seems to refer strictly to select statements.
I am attempting to implement some code in a trigger.

```
DECLARE v_fname, v_mname,v_lname,v_suffix, v_position VARCHAR(80);
DECLARE v_name VARCHAR(120);

SELECT first_name, middle_name, last_name, suffix into v_fname, v_mname, v_lname, v_suffix FROM people where objid = NEW.person_id;

SELECT v_fname, v_mname, v_lname, v_suffix,
CASE
  WHEN ((v_mname != "" OR v_mname IS NOT NULL) AND (v_suffix != "" OR v_suffix IS NOT NULL)) THEN SET v_name = CONCAT(v_fname,v_mname,v_lname,v_suffix)
  WHEN ((v_mname = "" OR v_mname IS NULL) AND (v_suffix != "" OR v_suffix IS NOT NULL)) THEN SET v_name = CONCAT(v_fname, v_lname, v_suffix)
  WHEN ((v_mname != "" OR v_mname IS NOT NULL) AND (v_suffix = "" OR v_suffix IS NULL)) THEN SET v_name = CONCAT(v_fname," ",v_mname," ",v_lname)
  ELSE SET v_name = CONCAT(v_fname," ",v_lname)
END CASE;
```

When I attempt to save the code I get an error:
[image]

The basic goal is to clean up the name data and output a concatenated list.

The problem is that some parts of the name are nonexistent, which causes problems in formatting or delivery of information when `CONCAT` encounters a `NULL`.

I've attempted using COALESCE and CONCAT_WS and they are not producing the results I want.

The result has 4 possibilities:

```
Joe J. Jones, Jr
Joe Jones, Jr
Joe J. Jones
Joe Jones
```

I had not used CASE before and it seemed as though it might be an elegant solution.

I'm going to go back to `IF THEN ELSE` but I'm curious if I exceeded what is possible here.

It's possible that I haven't solved this problem well, so I would appreciate insights or comments to help settle my curiosity here.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for the appropriate way to retrieve data from a different table, from within the trigger?

Comment: Did you look at the code that I put up? Based on what you are communicating I get the impression you didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use SET for assign a value to a column ..you just need  select  the columns eg: assuming you want the result v_name columns

```
    SELECT v_fname, v_mname, v_lname, v_suffix,
    CASE
      WHEN ((v_mname != "" OR v_mname IS NOT NULL) 
                        AND (v_suffix != "" OR v_suffix IS NOT NULL)) 
                THEN CONCAT(v_fname,v_mname,v_lname,v_suffix)
      WHEN ((v_mname = "" OR v_mname IS NULL) 
                        AND (v_suffix != "" OR v_suffix IS NOT NULL)) 
                THEN CONCAT(v_fname, v_lname, v_suffix)
      WHEN ((v_mname != "" OR v_mname IS NOT NULL) 
                        AND (v_suffix = "" OR v_suffix IS NULL)) 
                THEN  CONCAT(v_fname," ",v_mname," ",v_lname)
      ELSE CONCAT(v_fname," ",v_lname) as v_name
    END CASE;
```

Comment: Thanks.
Apparently combining !="" with IS NOT NULL evaluates to true.
That seems to have caused a problem.

Comment: In mysql the empty string and the null values have different meaning so .. the code should work .. instead the SET operato is used just for assigning var  and not values  to a columns ..

Comment: Got it. I switched over to IF ELSEIF to get this working. Will try case on another problem.